# reCAPTCHA Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, java-8, recaptcha

I had a running java project(Spring Boot on Java-8) which used reCAPTCHA google api in login module, I had the google key and secret key for validation and everything was working fine. Suddenly without any changes,when deploy the app and try to login at the verifying of reCaptcha key! the project couldn't run! and give me an error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Please anyone can till me why? or how can I fix!
Thanks in advance